# Linux - PHP mkdir creates directory, but no write permission?

Tags: php, linux

I run a php file by command line with the following code inside:

```
if(!is_dir($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0666, true);
}
```

No error is thrown for this code and the folder is created as expected.

If i do afterwards:

```
file_put_contents("Some data", $path . "filename.txt");
```

I get a "failed to open stream: Permission denied" exception.

Even if I do a

```
chmod($path, 0777);
```

after the mkdir inside the PHP Code, I get the error.

If I manually create the directory and set it to 777 by linux commands, everythig works fine. Why that?

Comment: you've been given an answer, ask them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission while creating the directory

`mkdir($path, 0777, true)`

also you need to change the syntax of file_put_contents to

`file_put_contents($path . "/filename.txt", "Some Data");`

Comment: I do that! I set permissions to 0666 which is enough for writing. Setting everything to 777 is a bad practice and not necessary in my case. And it doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: setting 777 bad idea, but to do so u need to set those permissions atleast 0744

Comment: @leftjustified, if you don't give execution permissions to a directory you cannot do anything inside it (like create a file).  write only allows you to erase files, as you don't need to access the file inside the directory, but not to create a file, as you always get a file descriptor to it, and you cannot get it, because you don't have access.